# Values in table on a .cshtml are not being updated after a post using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, html, razor

I need to show information on a table in 2.cshtml that is on another 1.cshtml page called using @Html.Action("Action","Controller"), depending on the row selected on a table inside of 1.cshtml, the problem is that the information is not being refresh after the view returns.

When you select a row in table (1.cshtml) javascript gives me the value of the cell that i need from that row, after that i do a ajax post to my controller and it access it succesfully then my controller returns the view and access my 2.cshtml with the table, then it runs in my for to display the information, but the problem is that my 2.cshtml never reloads so the rows of my table are never updated.

Code for posting to controller

```
function submitForm(row) {
        var idTool = el('idTool').value = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
        var url_ = '../Tools/ToolTable';
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url_,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ idToolPost:idTool })
        });
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ToolTable(int idToolPost)
{
    var entitieTool = new Models.ToolControlEntities2();
    List<Models.Tool> t = entitieTool.Tools.ToList();
    List<Models.Equip> eqp = entitieTool.Equips.Include(x => x.Equip_Tool).ToList();
    List<Models.Equip_Tool> eqpt = entitieTool.Equip_Tool.Include(x => x.Equip).Where(x => x.id_Tool == idToolPost).ToList();

    ToolEquip ttteqpceteqptflt = new ToolEquip(eqpt, t, eqp);
    ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "The information was succesfuly displayed.";

    return View(ttteqpceteqptflt);
}
```

Table to show result

```
    <table>
        <div>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> Tool</th>
                    <th> Equip</th>
                    <th> Active</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </div>
        <tbody>
            @for (int x = 0; x < Model.eqtool_.Count; x++)
            {
                <tr>

                    <td style="display: none"><input id="idEquip" name="eq[@x].id_Equip" type="hidden" value="@Model.eqtool_[x].id_Equip" /></td>
                    <td style="display: none"><input id="idEquip" name="eq[@x].id_Tool" type="hidden" value="@Model.eqtool_[x].id_Tool" /></td>
                    <td>@Model.eqtool_[x].Tool.Tool_Name</td>
                    <td>@Model.eqtool_[x].Equip.Equip_Name</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBox("@Model.eqtool_[x].active")</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

After it runs my for the page dosen't show the new information, here is where i think i'm missing a refresh somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So I resolve my issue I just used the following: 
the table was saved on my "texto" variable, and then I just replace the tbody (the information that i need) with the next line

```
document.getElementById('tooltabletbody').innerHTML = texto;
```